# Function to Compare Two Cells and Return the Smaller in Excel

Tags: excel

I'd think there'd be something to do this in Excel, because it seems so basic... BUT:

I have two cells and I need to compare them and return the lower of the two. This is very easily done with the following:

```
=IF(A1 > A2, A2, A1)
```

But in a complex formula, this seems insanely unnecessary.

It's also possible to do with:

```
=SMALL(A1:A2)
```

But of course my cells are not adjecent and don't make a range.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the [`MIN()` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/min.php).

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Min function:

=MIN(A1,A2)